# Reference for an undecidability proof

Tags: reference-request, proof-techniques, undecidability, decision-problem

I'm searching for a reference of an undecidability proof that is as simple as possible and starts "from scratch".

With "from scratch" I mean that it does not use some other undecidable problem to prove some undecidability (which is the usual case), I cannot wrap my mind about how proving undecidability that way (without a previous proof) could be possible.

This question may be inspiring: [An example of an easy to understand undecidable problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80745/an-example-of-an-easy-to-understand-undecidable-problem)

Also, I know this is probably not very objective, but it is important to me, it should be something as simple as possible, hopefully enough so that even I can understand it.

Comment: The first languages to be proven undecidable were - if I'm not mistaken - shown to be so via diagonalization. Unless you need a constructive proof, the most simple proof is that there is an uncountable number of languages but only a countable number of algorithms (since each word encodes at most one algorithm, and words are countable). If you are looking for a constructive proof, I would recommend to read Arora & Barak: Computational Complexity - A Modern Approach, p.25 under the heading "1.4 Uncomputable Functions".

Comment: G.Bach: diagonalization is a constructive proof, it gives an explicit language which is not decidable.

Comment: What's wrong with a basic proof of the undecidability of the halting problem? Consult, for instance, http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs5234/FAQ/halt.html

Comment: Since you don't give us any indication of which proof you don't get, I think this is covered by our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable). There is, of course, always my favorite [$\pi$ question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits) for developing intuition.

Comment: I found a [very simple proof](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs5234/FAQ/halt.html). I don't think it can get any more simple than that.

Answer (score 1):

to some degree all refs on the subject have a formidable inherent complexity due to the subject matter. however, here is a classic, highly accessible ref on Gödel's thm that may be helpful, written in "popular science" style by a philosopher & mathematics historian for a broad audience, breaking it down into intuitive everyday language.

- [Gödel's Proof](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814758371) Nagel/Newman

here are some other similar but more technical refs that may be helpful

- [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521674530) Smith
- [Gödel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812388) Franzén

there are also many refs on Turing's halting problem. one worth mentioning, a step-by-step walkthrough/tour of the original proof, but which is very advanced due to retaining all the mathematical complexity/detail:

- [The Annotated Turing: A Guided Tour Through Alan Turing's Historic Paper on Computability and the Turing Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470229055) Petzold

on the other hand most of the proof complexity of the halting problem is associated with the proof of the existence of the [Universal TM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine), wikipedia has a pretty good outline. this can be understood as a simulation or emulation of one machine by another. therefore studying the theory of [machine emulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_console_emulator) (now quite frequently applied with video games) may be helpful.

Comment: Since this is CS Stack Exchange, I assume the OP means "undecidability" in the sense of Turing machines, not Goedel.

Comment: DR to neophytes they seem dissimilar or disconnected but to theoreticians they are seen as basically instances of the [same phenomenon](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/halting-problem-uncomputable-sets-common-mathematical-proof). but agreed, wish there were more refs that were TM focused instead of Godel-focused, just citing what is available.