# Is the set of TMs that accept exactly two strings (each) semi-(decidable)?

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

I have found this problem-

> let A be the set of encoding of all those Turing machines that accept exactly two strings and let A' be the complement of A. Comment on whether A and A' are recursive , recursively enumerable or not recursively enumerable.

I am clueless at "exactly 2 strings". I have tried many books but I can't solve it. Please help.(Any hint is acceptable)

Comment: A is the set of Turing machines that recognize a language of the form {u, v} where u and v are distinct words. The question is basically whether A is decidable or not.

Comment: @Michael Blondin:Yes that's it.

Comment: Why are you "clueless at "exactly 2 strings""? What is your intuition, do you think it decidable or not?

Comment: @Michael Blondin:I think I have to reduce it in a way that I can show it undecidable. And I thought that after reading "RICE's theorem".Isn't it a non-trivial property of regular language?

Comment: Sounds like Rice's theorem.

Comment: @ Ran G: Actually, I can't model the proof or logic clearly. That's why I have asked here.

Comment: If you want to use Rice's theorem, you should show that it is a non trivial property, i.e. there is at least one TM with this property, and one TM without this property.

Comment: @Michael : Can you elaborate? I thank you for valuable comments.

Comment: @Ran:thanks. If you plase help on the proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial application of Rice's theorem.

Define:

$$S_A = \{ L \in RE \mid |L|=2\}$$

It is a non-trivial subset of $RE$ (for instance, it contains $\{0,1\}$ and it doesn't contain $\{\varepsilon\}$). Then By Rice's Theorem

$$ A = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in S_A\}$$ is undecidable. Note that $A$ is exactly the language stated in the question.

There is also an extended version of Rice's theorem that will show that $A$ is not even $RE$.

Comment: G:RE-recursively enumerable. How can you say that it is a subset RE.

Comment: $RE$ is just a set of languages. $S_A$ is also a set of languages $L\in RE$ therefore it is a subset of $RE$.

Comment: Good start. Now is $A$ co-RE?

Comment: @RickDecker the same method of extended Rice's theorem will show that the complement of $A$ is also not in $RE$. Maybe this extended rice form should be added to the [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/)