# Is it decidable whether a TM accepts more than one word?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

> Is the following language:
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle L= \{\langle M\rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM }, |L(M)|>1\}$
>
> Turing-decidable?

I think it isn't, because if a Turing machine T can decide L, then T can say if M stops or not (impossible this is the halting problem). So T accepts when M stops and accepts the string (with a length > 1) and refuses otherwise.

I want build a Turing machine S, based on T, that decide if M with an input w stops or not, but how I can build it?
If T exists then also S exists, so the halting problem would be Turing-decidable (impossible).

I think L is only Turing-recognizable. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: Just follow your idea and make it formal. See also [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable) which should give you some ideas.

Comment: The answer follows immediately from [Rice's theorem](http://kilby.stanford.edu/~rvg/154/handouts/Rice.html): the language is undecidable.

Comment: See answer to almost the same question [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33638/157). Voting to close as duplicate.