# How to show that the set of TMs that accept languages of size two is recognizable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

I know how to show $\overline{Lx}$ is unrecognizable.
I know how to show Lx is undecidable.

I would like the mapping reduction function that shows that Lx is recognizable or unrecognizable.

For instance, to show $\overline{Lx}$ is unrecognizable, show $\overline{Htm}$ <= $\overline{Lx}$

Given $\overline{Htm}$ = {M description: M is a TM and M loops on ''}

```
def R(<M>):
    def N(x):
        M('')
        if x == 0 or x == 1 then accept
    return <N>
```

> If M is in $\overline{Htm}$ then M loops then N will not accept any strings then
>   |L(N)| = 0 then N is in $\overline{Lx}$
>
> if M is not in $\overline{Htm}$ then M halts then N
>   will accept either 0 or 1 so |L(N)| = 2 then N is not in $\overline{Lx}$

I would like a similar proof to show that Lx is either recognizable or unrecognizable.

Comment: Duplicate of [Recursive ,recursively enumerable](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33637/recursive-recursively-enumerable), see the answer there.

Comment: @RanG. I don't think it's a duplicate please see edit. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate question, the extended version of Rice's theorem proves it is not RE. If you want to have a specific mapping reduction, how about doing the same reduction in your post, but always accepting $0$ and $1$, then running $M$, then accepting all other inputs. Now, if there is a loop then $|L|=2$ and otherwise it is infinite.

Comment: @RanG. To be fair, there's not actually an *answer* over there. (The extended theorem of Rice is neither widely known, nor do I know a good online resource.)

Comment: @Raphael  I hope to add it one day to the reference question. We should have a clear "usage" guide for Rice's thm.

Comment: @Raphael Finally, the extended version is part of the [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11289/157). (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on RanG. answer in comments.

To show ${Lx}$ is unrecognizable, show $\overline{Htm}$ <= ${Lx}$

Given $\overline{Htm}$ = {M description: M is a TM and M loops on ''}

```
def R(<M>):
    def N(x):
        if x == 0 or x == 1 then accept
        M('')
        return accept
    return <N>
```

> If M is in $\overline{Htm}$ then M loops then N will accept either 0 or 1 then
>   |L(N)| = 2 then N is in ${Lx}$
>
> if M is not in $\overline{Htm}$ then M halts then N
>   will accept all x so |L(N)| = $\infty$ then N is not in ${Lx}$