# Proving that $L=\{ \langle M \rangle \colon L(M)=L(M)^R \}$ is undecidable

Tags: computability, undecidability

I'm trying to show that
$L=\{ \langle M \rangle \colon L(M)=L(M)^R\}$ is undecidable, but I don't even know where to begin. Google wasn't much of a help, maybe because it's hard describing the language in words. Any hints?

Comment: Use Rice's theorem. If you don't know what that is, look it up and read the proof. Now you can prove your special case in the very same way.

Comment: What do you define $L(M)^{R}$ to be?

Comment: Every string in $L(M)^R$ is a reverse of some string in $L(R)$

Comment: "I don't even know where to begin" -- review your class material, textbooks, and [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable). "it's hard describing the language in words" -- what about "the set of Turing machines whose languages are closed against reversal"?