# Construct a semi decidable but not decidable set using the diagonal argument

Tags: complexity-theory

Not using anything other than the definition of SD and D

I know if A is SD, then there exists a TM M such that A = L(M), and A can be enumerated, and if A is decidable, then everything in A can be enumerated in some order.

How do I set up the diagonal matrix?

Comment: See the first part of http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11289/157   (link corrected)

Comment: @RanG. The first part is not good enough, since we want the language to be semidecidable. The usual trick is to show that some *specific* semidecidable language (say the halting problem) is decidable. The question is whether you could carry out the argument without knowing in advance about the halting problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus we construct there a co-semi decidable language, whose complement is semi-decidable. It fully answers the above question.

Comment: @RanG. I stand corrected.