# Decidability of the TM's computing a non-empty subset of total functions

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I have this HW problem:
Let $F$  be the set of computable total functions, and let $\emptyset\subsetneq S\subseteq F$. Denote 
$$L_S=\{ \langle M \rangle | M \text{ is a TM that computes a function and } f_M\in S \}$$

where $f_M$ is the function $M$ computes.

Prove that for every such none-trivial $S$, $L_S \notin \mathcal{R}$.

I tried to  construct

- $L_{f}=\left\{ x\#y\in{\Sigma^*}|y=f\left(x\right)\right\} $
- $\tilde{S}=\left\{ L_{f}|f\in S\right\} $
- $L_{\tilde{S}}=\left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle |L\left\langle M\right\rangle \in\tilde{S}\right\} $

and then show with Rice that $L_{\tilde{S}} \notin \mathcal{R}$, when the idea behind it was to eventually show that $L_{\tilde{S}} \leq_m L_S $.
But the problem here is that I couldn't show a mapping reduction from $L_{\tilde{S}}$ to $L_S$ without assuming $L_{\tilde{S}} \in \mathcal{RE}$ (which I'm quite sure is not true).
So any other directions will be warmly welcomed!

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.

Comment: I thaught that's what check-my-answer/proof tags are for.. but I'm willing to delete this question if you wish

Comment: The tag is there, as is [tag:c]. Doesn't mean we like most questions. I'd rather you make your question *good* than delete it.

Comment: The tag exists to warn you that this kind of question is generally unsuitable.  When you select the tag, a [one-sentence tag overview](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/check-my-answer/info) pops up, saying "Questions asking us to check whether your solution is correct are considered [off-topic](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and should not be posted on this site".

Comment: Didn't see the popup probably because of the browser I'm using wouldn't show it. I edited according to your comments. Thanke you @D.W.

Comment: "and then show with Rice" --  you are to *prove* Rice, so no using it.

Comment: You should clarify if you are allowed to use Rice's theorem or are you trying to prove it. For both cases, the answer can be found in http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11289/157

Comment: In a join efforts, we succeeded showing undecidability of $L_S$. It can be solved using Rice (a rather painful misuse of the theorem), but as @Raphael said - the more elegant way to show it, is to adjust the proof of Rice theorem to fit this case. I won't post an answer since I never accept my answers, and I'd like to see more ideas.

Comment: Posting (and accepting) your own answer is perfectly acceptabel and even encouraged. The content is here to stay and help more people in the future, after all!

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f: \Sigma^* \rightarrow \Sigma^*$, let

$$L_f = \{ x \# y \mid y = f(x) \}$$

For any Turing machine $M$, we can construct the description of a Turing machine $M'$ such that $M'$ recognizes $L_f$ if and only if $M$ computes $f$. $M'$ will receive a string, check that it is of the form $x \# y$ and then simulate $M$ with input $x$. If the simulation returns $w$, $M'$ accepts if $w = y$. Therefore, the language

$$ A_f = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM that computes the function $f$} \}$$

reduces to the language

$$B_f = \{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M) = L_f \}$$

The class

$$L_S = \{ L_f \mid f \in S \}$$

is a nontrivial class of Turing-recognizable languages and therefore the decision problem $B_f$ is undedicable by Rice's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct $\ \mathcal{C}=\{L\in\mathcal{RE}\ |\ \exists f\in S \ \text{such that}\ \ \mathrm{Im} f=L\}$ and it is clear That $\emptyset \subset \mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{RE}$ (because it is a set of languages from $\mathcal{RE}$ and it is clearly not empty and there are languges in $\mathcal{RE}$ that do not compute a computable function because they are not decidable)   and then by Rice's Theorem you get $\{\langle M\rangle \ |  \ L(M)\in\mathcal{C}\}\not \in \mathcal{R}$ and this language is exactly $L_S$ so $L_S \not \in \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: S is not in $\mathcal{RE}$ since it's not a set of languages.. Did you mean $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{RE}$? I don't see that eighther

Comment: @UriaMor yes and I provided a simple explanation

Comment: You are right... didn't notice at start

Comment: can you explain the line " there are languges in RE that do not compute a computable function because they are not decidable"?

Comment: @UriaMor remember that S is not trivial I'll explain why C!=RE so there is language in RE whose enumarator is a TM that writes the function that is not in S

Comment: S can be all F.

Comment: and this one is trivial look at the question : "for nontrivial S"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40385/discussion-between-uria-mor-and-lior).

Comment: The statement the OP is supposed to prove *is* Rice's theorem, so using it is cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Assume WLOG*   $Id\in S$ ($\forall x\in\Sigma^*:\ Id\left(x\right)=x$)

Define $f\left(\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \right)\mapsto\left\langle M'\right\rangle$  where $M'$ is a TM that on input x:

- if $M$ halts on $w$ then $M'$ accept (leave $x$ on the tape)

if $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in H_{TM}$ then $M'$ halts on every $x$ and the content of the tape by the end of the run is $x$ ($M'$ computes $Id$) - $\left\langle M'\right\rangle \in F$

if $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \notin H_{TM}$ then $M'$ never halts hence $\left\langle M'\right\rangle \notin F$.

Since $H_{TM}\leq_m L_{S}$ and $H_{TM}\notin\mathcal{R}$ we have $L_{S}\notin\mathcal{R}$.

**WLOG*:** if $Id\notin S$ prove for $\overline{S}=F\smallsetminus S$ - since now $Id\in\overline{S}$ the same proof holds, so $L_{\overline{S}}\notin\mathcal{R} L_{\overline{S}}=\left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle |f_{M}\notin S\right\}$ . Assume that $\overline{L_{S}}=\left\{ w\in\Sigma^*|\mbox{ if }w\mbox{ is an encoding of a TM then }w\mbox{ does not compute a function }f\in S\right\} \in\mathcal{R}$ and $R$ decides $\overline{L_{S}}$. We can construct a reduction f that on input $w$:

- if $R$ accepts $w$

  - check if w is a TM encoding
  - if w is a TM, accept
- reject

then $w\in\overline{L_{S}}$ iff $f\left(w\right)\in L_{\overline{S}}$ so we can decide $L_{\overline{S}}$ using $R$.

So $\overline{L_{S}}\notin\mathcal{R}\implies L_{S}\notin\mathcal{R}$