# Classify the set of all TMs whose languages from the accepting problem

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

Let $$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine so } A_{TM}  \leq_m L(M) \}$$
The question is whether $L$ is in $\mathcal{R}, \mathcal{RE}, co-\mathcal{RE}$ or in $\overline{\mathcal{RE} \cup co-\mathcal{RE}}$ ?

I gained some progrees showing  $L \notin co- \mathcal{RE}$:

Define reduction $f:A_{TM}\rightarrow L$ on input $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle$ returns:

- if $M$ accepts $w$ return $ \left\langle U_{TM}\right\rangle $ 
  ($L \left(U_{TM}\right)=A_{TM}$ so $\left\langle U_{TM}\right\rangle \in L$)
- if $\left\langle M\right\rangle$ rejects $w$ return 1 (not a TM encoding hence not in L)

$f$ is computable and $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in A_{TM}\iff f\left(\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \right)\in L$ hence $A_{TM}\leq_m L \implies L\notin co-\mathcal{RE}$.

Now I want to show that $L \notin \mathcal{RE}$. And I'm stuck..

Notation:

$A_{TM} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid  M \text{ is a TM}, w \in L(M)\}$

$H_{TM} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid  M \text{ is a TM and $M$ halts on $w$} \}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept RE-hardness? Try to prove that $A_{TM}$ is RE-hard (in fact, RE-complete). This should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, it was briefly mentioned so it's not the first time I hear the term. I'll dive into it. Thankes!

Comment: I'm not sure what your plan is with $\mathcal{C}$; it seems mostly unrelated to $L$. Or does $L_C$ denote its index set? Then you'd still have to show that $\mathcal{C} \not\in \{\emptyset, 2^{\Sigma^*} \}$ before you can apply Rice's theorem.

Comment: No... it was a mistake. Ive edited accordingly. Thankes!

Comment: See the extended version of Rice's theorem, http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11289/  (sec 4.1)

Comment: I'm sorry Ran.. I'm familiar with the RE-complete definition. But I can't see how any of youre links is related to the language in the question, except for it being consisted of encodings of TMs that are enumerating RE-complete languages.

Comment: Did you just change the question from $A \le L$ to $L \le A$? This totally changes the language.

Comment: Yes.. as I told Raphael on a previews  comment - it was a mistake

Comment: @RanG. I have no problams shoing that the language is undecidable. Rice doesn't say anything regarding RE membership, and this is the part where I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the extended version of Rice's theorem clearly states this language is not in $RE$. Nevertheless, let us prove this claim via a direct reduction from a language known not to be in $RE$, let's say 
$$ \overline{HP} = \{\langle M,w\rangle \mid M \text{ doesn't halts on }w \}$$

We will show that $\overline{HP} \le L$ and conclude that $L \notin RE$.

The reduction will assume we have a machine that recognizes $A_{TM}$ (call it $R$) and goes as follow. Given an input $\langle M,w\rangle$ we construct the output string $\langle M_w\rangle$ which is a machine that, on input x, does:

1. repeat the loop:
   1.1 run one step of $M$ on $w$
   1.2 run one step of $R$ on $x$
   1.3  if 1.1 halts - the machine $M_w$ rejects. If 1.2 accepts - the machine $M_w$ accepts.

It is easy to verify this is a computable reduction. Let's just verify it is valid.

Case I: $\langle M,w\rangle\notin \overline {HP}$, then eventually (say after $T$ steps)  $M$ will halt on $w$ before the computation of 1.2 concludes, thus $L(M_w)$ can be **decided** in less then $T$ steps and in particular it is decidable. Therefore $A_{TM} \not\le L(M_w)$ and thus $\langle M_w\rangle \notin L$.

Case II: $\langle M,w\rangle\in \overline {HP}$, then $M$ never halts on $w$, which means that only step 1.2 is relevant, which means that $M_w$ behaves in this case just like $R$. So it holds that $L(M_w) = A_{TM}$ and in particular, $A_{TM} \le L(M_w)$. Then, $\langle M_w \rangle \in L$.