# Proof (by contradiction) of the emptiness problem

Tags: computability, reductions, proof-techniques, undecidability

I fail to understand the proof of the Emptiness Problem

$E_{TM} = \{\langle M \rangle | M $ is a TM and $L(M) = \emptyset\}$

---

[image]

1) Use the description of $M$ and $w$ to construct $M_1$, which on Input $x$ behaves as follows:

1. If $x \neq w$, reject
2. If $x = w$, run $M$ on input $w$ and accept if $M$ does

2) Run $R$ on input $\langle M_1\rangle$

3) If $R$ accepts, reject; if $R$ rejects, accept

---

I do understand the basic idea of a reduction and in particular the reduction of $A_{TM}$ to $Halt_{TM}$, however,

- I do not see how $E_{TM}$ could be used as a subroutine to solve $A_{TM}$. The whole construction of $M_1$ confuses me a lot. To me it looks like $M_1$ is just like a filter that rejects everything except $w$
- But why does $M_1$ even have to check if $x$ equals $w$? As soon as $S$ is fed with a particular pair $\langle M,w\rangle$, $x$ will be equal to $w$, no? how can it be anything different than $w$?

Comment: This is **not** proof by contradiction. It is a proof of negation.

Answer (score 3):

1. $M_1$ rejects everything, including $w$, *unless $M$ accepts it* (crucial). $M_1$ will then be a machine that always rejects, if and only if $M$ rejects $w$.
2. The white box treats $M$ and $w$ as constants. They are still something that $S$ received as input, and we know that.
3. $R$ is a **hypothetical** machine that decides if its input is a machine that always rejects.
4. $S$ will receive **unknown** $\langle M,w \rangle$ as its input. Should $R$ work as intended, then $S$ in fact solves the *general* problem of deciding if $M$ accepts $w$, which is exactly $A_{TM}$.
5. It has been proven that $A_{TM}$ is not decidable.

Therefore,

6. $R$ cannot exist.

   Our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable) has more information on the subject. You may find particularly interesting to see how this kind of proof can be generalized (look for Rice's theorem).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The work flow is as following:

1. $A_{TM}$ is a turing machine, w is its input.
2. Modified $A_{TM}$: add condition logic in front of it to construct a new turing machine $E_{TM}$.
3. $E_{TM}$ takes input x, then the condition logic inside $E_{TM}$ first check if(w!=x) reject.
4. If (w==x), let w = x, then feed w to $A_{TM}$.
5. $A_{TM}$ may have three possible behavior: accept on w; reject on w; loop forever(not halt).
6. Assume we have a turing machine $R_{TM}$ which decide $E_{TM}$:

   - If $R_{TM}$ rejects on <$E_{TM}$, x>, which means the language of $E_{TM}$ is NOT ∅. then $E_{TM}$ must accepted on input x. Which means w==x AND $A_{TM}$ accepts w.
   - If $R_{TM}$ accepts on <$E_{TM}$, x>, which means the language of $E_{TM}$ is ∅. then $E_{TM}$ must reject on input x. Which means ω != x OR w==x and $A_{TM}$ rejects w too.
7. Now let's construct another new turing machine $S_{TM}$:

   - Let $S_{TM}$ accepts If $R_{TM}$ rejects on <$E_{TM}$, w> (NOTE: the input is w, not x).Which means $A_{TM}$ accepts on input w.
   - Let $S_{TM}$ rejects If $S_{TM}$ accepts on <$E_{TM}$, w> (NOTE: the input is w, not x).Which means $A_{TM}$ rejects on input w.

Then we have: $S_{TM}$ decide $A_{TM}$ on input w.

**Contradiction happens.**

So **$E_{TM}$ is undecidable.**