# How to prove $\{\langle M\rangle: L(M)=\emptyset\}$ is undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability

Consider the language $$E_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: L(M)=\emptyset\}.$$ Prove that $E_{T M} \in \text{coRE} \backslash\text{R}.$

I proved that $$E_{T M} \in\text{coRE}$$
using Turing machine I built which recognizes the completement of the language. What left is to show that it is not in $$ R$$

Any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: This question should have been answered somewhere on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that a function is not computable? How to show a language is not computably enumerable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable-how-to-show-a-language-is-not-com)

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove that is to reduce complement of A TM to E TM.

For Turing machine M and w as its input. We construct M' as follows:

For input w':

Run M on w:

If M rejected w, reject w'.

Otherwise, accept w'.

It is easy to see that M accepts w if and only if M' belongs to E TM.

From this reduction, we can deduct that E TM beings to coRE. And it doesn't belong to RE. If it does, Then E TM would be computable which contradicts the fact that A TM's complement is reducible to E TM.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{HALT}_{TM} \leq_m E_{TM}$. Define a machine $H$ on input $\langle M, w \rangle$ as follows:

```
H(<M, w>):
    Construct a machine M' defined as follows:
    M'(x):
        Run M on w for |x| steps
          if (M halts on w after |x| steps)
             Accept x
          else
             Reject x
    Output <M'>
```

If $\langle M, w \rangle \in \overline{HALT}_{TM}$, then $M$ never halts on $w$, which means $L(M') = \emptyset$ and $\langle M' \rangle \in E_{TM}$. If $\langle M, w \rangle \notin \overline{HALT}_{TM}$, then $M$ halts on $w$ after some finite number of steps, $k$, thus, on inputs string $x$ such that $|x| \geq k$, $M'$ accepts $x$, which means $L(M') \neq \emptyset$ and $\langle M' \rangle \notin E_{TM}$.

Since we can reduce $\overline{HALT}_{TM}$ to $E_{TM}$, if $E_{TM}$ is recognizable, then $\overline{HALT}_{TM}$ is recognizable and the halting problem is decidable (since we know $HALT_{TM}$ is recognizable), a contradiction. Thus, $E_{TM} \notin RE$, which means $E_{TM} \notin R$.